# When do qml predicates assigned to properties get evaluated?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

When writing code like:

```
Item{
    id: item
    enabled:  backend.property == "X"
}
```

When does the predicate get evaluated. once? or every time property changes?

furthermore, how does it applies when the property is assigned in a state change: is it evaluated once at state change or each time the property change is signaled?

```
    State {
        name: "One"
        when: step == 2

        PropertyChanges {
            target: item
            enabled:  backend.property == "X"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is evaluated everytime any of the properties taking place in the predicate are changed (by means of the `Q_PROPERTY(... NOTIFY signalX)`). In your example this can be `backend` or `property`.

The `PropertyChanges` in your example will do the same, it will get evaluated every time any of the properties changes. If you assign `true` to the `explicit` property, it will be a once-off evaluation, the moment the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that yourself by putting breaks or print statements in the property setter. The QML variable is evaluated every time the notify signal is called, i.e. emit propChanged() in the case below. The predicate will be re-evaluated too when emit propChanged() is called, which is logical else you would have inconsistent states.

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString prop READ getProp WRITE setProp NOTIFY propChanged);

private:
    QString m_prop;

public:
    void setProp(QString prop) {
        if (prop != m_prop) {
            m_prop = prop;
            // log or break here
            emit propChanged();
        }
    }
    QString getProp() const { return m_prop; }

signals:
    void propChanged();
```